# How to prove $(B \backslash P)^{-1} (A \otimes_B B)$ is isomorphic to $A \otimes_B B_P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

I am trying to prove $(B \backslash P)^{-1} (A \otimes_B B)$ is isomorphic to $A \otimes_B B_P$ for a commutative ring with unity $B$, $A$ a $B$-algebra and a prime ideal $P$ of $B$. I have been trying to prove this by the universal property of the localisation map and the tensor products.. maybe there is a simpler way? Thank you.

Edit: I think one way of proving this is to define a map
$$
(B \backslash P)^{-1} (A \otimes_B B) \to A \otimes_B B_P
$$
by sending $\frac{a \otimes b}{x}$ to $a \otimes \frac{b}{x}$, and extending it by linearity. We can also define a map
$$
A \otimes_B B_P \to (B \backslash P)^{-1} (A \otimes_B B) 
$$
by sending $a \otimes \frac{b}{x}$ to $\frac{a \otimes b}{x}$, and extending it by linearity. 
We can see that these maps are inverses to each other so they are isomorphic. However, how can I show these maps are well defined? Thank you!

Comment: In which ring is $P$ a prime ideal?

Comment: fixd, thank you

Comment: Recall the canonical $B$-algebra isomorphism $A\cong A\otimes_BB$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
&\lambda:B\to B_{\mathfrak P}&
&b\mapsto b/1
\end{align}
denote the canonical ring homomorphism.
Then we get a $B$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi=1_A\otimes_B\lambda:A\otimes_BB\to A\otimes_BB_{\mathfrak P}$.
Since for every $s\in B\setminus\mathfrak P$, the element $\varphi(1\otimes s)=1\otimes(s/1)$ is invertible in $A\otimes_BB_{\mathfrak P}$, with inverse $1\otimes (1/s)$, by universal property of ring localization, $\varphi$ extends uniquely to a $B_{\mathfrak P}$-algebra homomorphism
\begin{align}
&\bar\varphi:(B\setminus\mathfrak P)^{-1}(A\otimes_BB)\to A\otimes_BB_{\mathfrak P}&
&(a\otimes b)/s\mapsto a\otimes(b/s)
\end{align}

Conversely, we have $B$-algebra homomorphisms
\begin{align}
&\alpha:A\to(B\setminus\mathfrak P)^{-1}(A\otimes_BB)&
&a\mapsto(a\otimes 1)/1\\
&\beta:B\to(B\setminus\mathfrak P)^{-1}(A\otimes_BB)&
&b\mapsto(1\otimes b)/1
\end{align}
Since for every $s\in B\setminus\mathfrak P$ the element $\beta(s)=(1\otimes s)/1$ is invertible in $A\otimes_BB_{\mathfrak P}$ with inverse $(1\otimes 1)/s$, by universal property of ring localization, $\beta$ extends uniquely to a $B$-algebra homomorphism $\bar\beta:B_{\mathfrak P}\to(B\setminus\mathfrak P)^{-1}(A\otimes_BB)$.
By universal property of tensor product, we get a $B$-algebra homomorphism
\begin{align}
&A\otimes_BB_{\mathfrak P}\to(B\setminus\mathfrak P)^{-1}(A\otimes_BB)&
&a\otimes(b/s)\mapsto(a\otimes b)/s
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have a few questions: 1) How do we know that the map $1_A \otimes_B \lambda$ is well defined? 2) Is the last map $\alpha \otimes \overline{\beta}$? and how do we know $1 \otimes (1/s)$ is sent to $(1 \otimes 1)/s$?

Comment: 1) In general, if $\xi:X\to X'$ and $\psi:Y\to Y'$ are $B$-algebra homomorphisms, then $\xi\otimes_B\psi:X\otimes_BY\to X'\otimes_BY'$ is a $B$-algebra homomorphism as well. 2) the last map is given by $a\otimes(b/s)\mapsto\alpha(a)\bar\beta(b/s)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!